# Why does Zero not answer Jonathan's question about corporate decision making?

Tags: rollerball-1975

Rollerball (1975) contains a scene in which Jonathan, the main character, visits a computerized library in order to learn the basics of corporate governance. However, when Zero (the AI supercomputer) is asked how corporate decisions are made it initially doesn't answer. Once physically assaulted by the librarian it provides only a basic explanation ("corporate decisions are made by corporate executives").

I understand that in the fictional world of Rollerball there is essentially no transparency in the corporate-government world. However, I'm confused about Zero's response. I can't tell whether:

- Zero doesn't know. The librarian earlier mentioned that it recently misplaced an entire century's worth of data.
- Zero has the data, but can't or won't formulate a response. The librarian's comments on the way to Zero's chamber suggested that Zero has started producing ambiguous, unhelpful answers. It isn't clear if this is malfunction or some emergent personality.
- Zero has the data, but is prohibited from telling. The librarian suggests providing only a simple answer, which suggests to me that maybe it is a security or permissions issue.
- Zero has the data, but simply won't tell. The librarian's comments about Zero's personality made it sound like the computer is obstinate.

So what's going on with Zero? Why won't it answer the question?

Comment: No help in the short story; [Roller Ball Murder](https://instruct.uwo.ca/kinesiology/378/files/essays/roller.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely practical explanation seems to be that Zero is forbidden from providing information that its corporate masters do not want disseminated.  Whether that means, more specifically, that Zero's knowledge of such matters has been erased, or that it is simply forbidden to release such information is unknown.  Zero's keeper, played by Ralph Richardson, is extremely amicable but also seems to be at least borderline insane; yet he is kept around as the machine's keeper and overseer—which suggests that the fact that Zero itself also appears to be incapable of conveying useful information is probably intentional.

However, at a meta level, the uselessness of Zero is just another thematic indication that a major element of the strange dystopia depicted in *Rollerball* is people's general absence of understanding of anything outside their immediate circumstances.  Even a relatively privileged individual like Jonathan E. has no way to find out what is really going around him, and the viewer is in a similar quandary.  (One of the things that that *Rollerball* does well is to draw the viewer into the weird world it depicts.  It is not so easy to watch some of the movie's sporting confrontations without getting into the thrill of rooting for the Houston team—even for a viewer who understands that the Rollerball game is really a pointlessly violent horror exhibition.)

The setting raises all sorts of questions—How did the the world of *Rollerball* develop?  Who is really in control?  Is there any hope of real change?—and never even attempts to answer most of them.  The viewer does get a reasonably clear explanation of the role that the sport of Rollerball plays in the dystopian society, but that is about it.  The opportunity offered by Zero is tantalizing to both Jonathan and the viewer, but neither one gets any satisfaction.  The episode with Zero is just another instance where it turns out to be impossible to learn anything useful—to the point where Jonathan and the viewer are left with no real understanding even of why the desired answers were unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I initially didn't accept it because it didn't directly answer the question. However, after letting it sit for a while I came to appreciate how you artfully redirected my question into a more interesting one.